# Операторы '||' и 'or'

Tags: php

Доброго времени.

Сейчас работал с базой и озадачился вопросом:

```
$db_res = sqlite_open( $db_name ) || die ("Ошибка при открытии БД!" );
$query = sqlite_query($db_res, "SELECT * FROM $table") || die ('Ошибка в запросе!');
```

При использовании "|| die()" получаю ошибку

> `Warning: sqlite_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in ... on line ...`
> `Ошибка в запросе!`

Если изменить оператор "||" на "or" все работает правильно, почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело в том, что оператор `||`  имеет более высокий [приоритет](http://php.net/operators.precedence), чем оператор `=`, по этому `$db_res` будет присвоен результат выражения `sqlite_open( $db_name ) || die ("Ошибка при открытии БД!" )`, т.е. true.

Оператор `or` наоборот имеет более низкий [приоритет](http://php.net/operators.precedence), чем `=`, следовательно сначала `$db_res` будет присвоен результат `sqlite_open( $db_name )` и только потом будет применено логическое ИЛИ: `$db_res || die ("Ошибка при открытии БД!" )`

Т.е. если явно расставить приоритеты, то оба выражения будут выглядеть так:

```
$db_res = ( sqlite_open( $db_name ) || die ("Ошибка при открытии БД!" ) );
( $db_res = sqlite_open( $db_name ) ) or die ("Ошибка при открытии БД!" );
```

Comment: Ок, спасибо, теперь точно всё понятно.

Answer (score 0):

А соглашения о программировании говорят об приоритете использования операторов OR и AND перед || и &&. Так что я советую использовать буквенный вариант.